# advise on app architecture: drag drop connect

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, collision-detection, flowchart

I want to build an iPhone and iPad app that works like  [MIT's Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/)

[image]

So I basically need to drag n drop the blocks from the left to the right side, in order to build a flow chart style diagram...
And then connect them and according to that connection have different behaviours, like you would expect in a flow chart diagram; also some of the blocks should have a textField for editing values...

So what way would you guys recommend to go to accomplish this?, Keeping it as simple as possible.

Edit [thanks to @Codafi for the heads up]:
 [in this link some of the story of Apple rejecting the Scratch app](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/04/apple-scratch-app/)

Very interesting!
but i dont plan to Violate the clause 3.3.2, which states iPhone apps may not contain code interpreters other than Apple’s. The clause reads:

> An Application may not itself install or launch other executable code by any means, including     without limitation through the use of a plug-in architecture, calling other frameworks, other APIs or otherwise. No interpreted code may be downloaded or used in an Application except for code that is interpreted and run by Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in interpreter(s).

I would just like to construct the flow diagram and make it generate some animation logo style

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I love scratch and would love any similar app but I am afraid that in doing something similar, your app will be rejected by Apple for the same reason the scratch app was: downloading and interpreting code.  I have seen a circuit builder app, however, that is debatably similar to code so it is possible.  A good design, though.  It might also be nice to have an option to move blocks by tapping rather than sliding to increase accuracy.

Comment: please check the edit, as I understand it is not because it was close to programming that it was rejected, it was rejected because the clause 3.3.2?? [see edit] Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had not actually seen the cause, just read an article that described it as being too close to programming.  Thank you for sharing the actual text of the clause.